# Move SQL for View Into Manageable Chunks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following code in SQL:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT Form_Title 
     FROM Forms 
     WHERE Form_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 Form_ID 
                      FROM [Form_Responses] 
                      WHERE [Form_Response_ID] = [Form_Response_ID])) AS Form_Name
FROM 
    [FooDb].[dbo].[Submissions]
```

In essence, I am selecting data three tables "away" and nesting all these selections. So I select a field from one table, and use it to make selection in another.

I can't use vars in a view, so how do I make this remotely readable?

Edit - the pseudocode below is what I was going for with the SQL above and it works, but I don't know how to make it clean, and that's the question:

```
//Form_Response_ID exists on Submissions
SELECT Get_Query_Result(Form_Response_ID) as Form_Name
FROM Submissions

Get_Query_Result(Form_Response_ID)() {
     return SELECT Form_Title FROM Forms WHERE Form_ID = Get_Form_Id(Form_Response_ID);
}

// Form_Responses has Form_Response_ID as well
Get_Form_Id(Form_Response_ID) {
    return SELECT TOP 1 Form_ID FROM [Form_Responses] WHERE [Form_Response_ID] = Form_Response_ID
}
```

Comment: It's extremely difficult to understand what you are trying to do with that SQL code alone. Please share some sample data and your desired results.

Comment: @JNevill My code works - my issue is EXACTLY what you described - no one can understand what the hell I just wrote. Basically, there are three nested SELECT statements. I want some way to break it out into variables. Functions come to mind, I guess. This has to be in a view - I can't use vars. I am asking about how to make it more readable.

Comment: You have WHERE [Form_Response_ID] = [Form_Response_ID] in your subquery  this is like 1=1  so you want select all  the row from  [Form_Responses] ?

Comment: What @scaisEdge just said. Your code is not doing what you think it's doing. It's hard to understand what you are trying to do. It looks like you are trying to do a correlated subquery to grab a value from another table, but that's not what's happening here.

Comment: @JNevill updated.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the query you are looking for is like below

```
select f.Form_Title as Form_Name
from
Forms f JOIN Form_Responses fr
on f.Form_ID=fr.Form_ID
JOIN Submissions s 
on fr.Form_Response_ID=S.Form_Response_ID
```

Comment: Might be, maybe I am just too tired. But anyway, I need some way not to have so much code in a single line. I am going to be doing the same complex manipulation for 15 other fields.